# cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python

I am trying to do sentiment analysis using python 3.6. I can't understand what's wrong... Please check this code.i am using .csv file in excel You can find the dataset that i'm using [here](https://github.com/YoeriNijs/TweetAnalyzer%60).
.Output:

> Please enter a filename (.csv): data.csv
>   File opened successfully!
>   Wait a sec for the results... File "C:\Users\Nahid\Downloads\Compressed\TweetAnalyzer-master\TweetAnalyzer-master\script.py", line 62, in  
>   cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets)
>    File "C:\Users\Nahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py", line 199, in train for fname, fval in featureset.items(): AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

data link:https://github.com/YoeriNijs/TweetAnalyzer

Here's my code so far:

```
import nltk, random, csv, sys
from nltk.corpus import names
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from textblob import TextBlob

def selectTweets(row):
    tweetWords = []
    words = row[0].split()
    for i in words:
        i = i.lower()
        i = i.strip('@#\'"?,.!')
        tweetWords.append(i)
    row[0] = tweetWords

    if counter <= 499:
        trainTweets.append(row)
    else:
        testTweets.append(row)

trainTweets = []
testTweets = []


print ("Tweet Sentiment Analyzer by Yoeri Nijs")
print ("*" * 30)


while True:
    # Ask for filename
    filename =  str(input("> Please enter a filename (.csv): "))
    #Check if filename ends with .csv
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):

        try:

            #Open file
            with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')

               #Print succes message
                print ("> File opened successfully!")

                counter = 0
                for row in reader:
                    selectTweets(row)
                    counter += 1

                print ("> Wait a sec for the results...")


                cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets)

                print ('accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(c1, testTweets))
                c1.show_most_informative_features()
        except IOError:
            print ("File does not exist.")

    #Else if file does not end with .csv, do this
    else:
        print ("Please open a file that ends with .csv")
```

Comment: When asking for help, please help others help you. Please provide more background information, such as what kind of data are you trying to feed in to the classifier, what format (or shape) is the data in, what methods have you tried already, what were the outcomes, etc.

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: i am using .csv file in excel.Output:
> Please enter a filename (.csv): data.csv
> File opened successfully!
> Wait a sec for the results...
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\Downloads\Compressed\TweetAnalyzer-master\TweetAnalyzer-master\script.py", line 62, in <module>
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets)
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py", line 199, in train
    for fname, fval in featureset.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: cl = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainTweets)## this line produce error

                print ('accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(c1, testTweets))
                c1.show_most_informative_features()